# Markdown asterisk logic

Tags: markdown

I would like to emphsize the `un?` (with hyphen) in

```
un?related
```

in Markdown, and have not found a way to do that. The obvious

```
_un?_related
*un?*related
```

do *not* work.

Apparently, `*` is more robust than `_` in that it can be used to emphasize parts of words,

```
a*b*c
```

(This works, `a_b_c` doesn't.) However, if a non-alphanumeric character is present at next to either of the bordering `*`, this won't work either.

Any hints?

Comment: Just use the lower level HTML emphasis tags instead of the markdown syntax: `<em>un?</em>related`

Comment: Seems to be part of the specs since the char after the emphasise isn't a newline, or any other valid ones. Using Mike's suggestion is probably the only way

Comment: @0stone0 Can you point me to the part of the spec you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile and can't find it that easily, there have been questions like this before that showed the right specs if I remember correctly. Might search tomorrow when behind a PC.

Comment: Which one do you want? There's like 10 different markdown specs. However, all of them go "you can just stick HTML in here, I don't care" because 99.99% of the time markdown gets converted to HTML so you can actually read in in a nicely styled fashion, and those HTML tags will simply do what they need to. Markdown's stance is "if it's not my syntax, I'm not doing anything with it, it's up to whatever renders this document to interpret". (So in this case if: if your target is _not_ a browser or browseresque view, talk about what your target is for a target-specific solution).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm looking for what 0stone0 talks about, i.e., "char after the empasise isn't a newline" etc. HTML is fine, but I prefer the Markdown syntax for readability. I'd like to use it as often as possible, which is why I need to know when exactly I can't.

Comment: That _really_ depends on _exactly_ which markdown parser you're using, because I wasn't joking, there are LOTS of competing markdown specifications, and they're all "similar, but subtly different". And yes, there's "common markdown", but that was an attempt to unify all the different specs, and in good old tradition: just ended up being "yet another spec" instead. Some folks use it, others don't. Consequentially, markdown simply doesn't _have_ an official spec, just lots of opinions based on who wrote a parser for it, and you need to know which one you're using to know what it can do.

Comment: I know that Markdown isn't standardized, and that there are many implementations. They all seem to have this particular behavior in common though, at least the implementations I've tested.

Comment: And you're _still_ going to have to look at which one you're using, then look up which flavour it's based on, so you can look up exactly what it's supposed to do (because otherwise you're just guessing, and guessing is not the same as knowing. The worst thing you can do is convince yourself that your guess is a good enough reflection of reality =).

Comment: Do you know an implementation that behaves differently in this particular aspect?